# Is there a verilog coding style checker or formatter?

Tags: verilog

Verilog is a unique language, compare with other programming language or description language. But it is very easy to write some buggy code if you don't follow good coding style like "Don't combine multiple l-value in one always blocks". [netFPGA Verilog coding guideline](https://github.com/NetFPGA/netfpga/wiki/VerilogCodingGuidelines). Is there a verilog coding style checker or formatter like php_cs or php_md with PSR2 rule in verilog development?

Comment: A verilog compiler is a checker as well. So, fix your compilation bugs. As for formatter (ant light-weight linter), you can find a bunch of them, including 'emacs', modes or IDE extensions, e.g. in eclipse. There is a bunch of professional linting tools as well. So, just look for them. It is not that unique after al.

Comment: I know emacs have some tool. Is there a other code formatter ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do formatting, but Verilator has built-in linting (`--lint-only -Wall`)